# Область видимости global при использовании Multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing, область-видимости

В примере ниже переменная `STOP` меняет свое значение после работы функции `func()`:

```
def func(x):
    global STOP
    STOP = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    STOP = False
    result = list(map(func, [1]))
    print(STOP)
```

В следующем примере при применении `multiprocessing.Pool` переменная `STOP` не меняет свое значение:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(x):
    global STOP
    STOP = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    STOP = False
    with Pool() as p:
        result = p.map(func, [1])
    print(STOP)
```

**Каким образом можно добиться изменения значения переменной глобально при изпользовании** `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: В каждом процессе, созданном через multiprocessing, будут свои глобальные переменные, не связанные между собой. В вашем случае придется использовать например `multiprocessing.Event()`.

Comment: @insolor Не могли бы вы подробнее расписать, какое предназначение у `Event()`. Хотелось бы понять, каким образом внедрить его в код

Comment: Предназначение - передача событий между процессами. Посмотрите примеры кода в этом ответе, там более-менее все понятно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100700/4752653

Comment: Если использование `multiprocessing` не самоцель, используйте [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) с `ThreadPoolExecutor`